# Turbolinks and code in Application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Ok, first time using Turbolinks.  Overall, I'm pleased, but I have one issue: there is code in my application layout (simple header code, shows your info if you are logged in, otherwise a login form) that doesn't get reloaded when the data changes.

This makes sense - as its not within a yield, its in my application layout and Turbolinks shouldn't run it.

But is there an easy way to trigger turbolinks to regenerate that portion of the page?

Comment: Turbolinks uses push-state to replaces entire body of a html document so your header should relode properly. can you post your application.html.erb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

A big problem you'll find with `Turbolinks` is the way in which it will only update the `<body>` of your page - leaving the `<head>` intact.

This means if you have logic in the `<head>` of your HTML layout, it won't change if you're loading a page with the same `<head>` area.

--

**Setup**

The solution I use is to just put the logic in the `<body>` of the page. We use the following:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body>
   <% if user_signed_in? %>
       ...
   <% else %>
       ...
   <% end %>
```

This works for us in every application we've done it in - all using turbolinks.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'm doing... The "header" I speak of is entirely within the body - but when that data changes, its NOT re-rendering the stuff in my application layout.  If it works for you though, then I must be doing something else wrong somewhere and maybe this is a red herring.  I'll dig deeper - thanks.

Comment: Can you post your entire application layout in your question? It will be interesting to see whether you're using `devise` or not

Comment: I'm definitely not using devise.  I'm using homegrown auth.  Which might be the problem.  I'll dig into it first and if I get stumped I'll post something that's been cleaned up and public viewable.

Comment: Well, I have NO idea why, but it is working now.  So I'm chalking it up to something wrong in my code elsewhere that I've fixed.

For future searchers: it DOES work. Application layout WILL re-render in turbolinks as long as its in the body tag.